# Grails inheritance concern

Tags: grails, inheritance

When a domain class inherits from a parent domain class in Grails, do static mappings and static constraints also get inherited or must they be restated in children classes?

Does inheritance only work in domain classes or can controllers and services inherit also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers and Services can be inherited as well as domain classes. for controllers see the official example of `RestfulController` Superclass in the [doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/webServices.html#extendingRestfulController). To do inheritance on domain classes, there are some thigs, that have to be recognized like the inheritance of the mapping closure. For more information see [here](http://btiernay.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/inheriting-column-mappings-in-gorm/). For Services, it could also be reasonable to use mixins as an alternative (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125053/inheritance-or-service-for-common-domain-methods)).